# PutExtra em várias acitivity

Tags: android, imageview

Bom, o que quero fazer é o seguinte. Quero criar uma imagem através do app.
Pra criar essa imagem, o usuário vai escolher 3 imagens. Então pra escolhe-las, ele vai ter que passar pela Activity1 e escolher a primeira imagem. Quando ele escolher, grava a imagem numa variável ou num `putextra` como eu tava pensando em fazer e abre a Activity2. Faz isso de novo pra Activity3. Então. É possível ter vários `putextra` passando de Activity pra Activity? Essas imagens vem de uma url armazenada no banco.

Atualmente faço com algo parecido com `putextra`, mas é só em uma activity e uma imagem.

Assim:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //passa "name" para a classe Detail fazer uma busca;
            intent = new Intent(getContext(), Detail.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", names.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("update", true);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

Na classe Detail:

```
   isUpdate = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("update", false);
    if (isUpdate) {
        databaseAccess.open();
        //aqui pega o "name" e faz uma busca no banco pra trazer a imagem
        data = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        getimage = databaseAccess.getImageS(data);
```

Recuperando a imagem:

```
 //aqui recupera a imagem e de volta em detail seto ela num 
// imageview via Picasso
public String getImageS(String name) {
    String data = null;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT imagem FROM Armas WHERE nome = ?", new String[]{name});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        data = cursor.getString(0);
        break;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Passa a primeira imagem pra activity 2. Depois, na activity 2, pega a segunda imagem e passa ela com  a primeira imagem para a activity 3. 2 Extras.

Comment: Já pensou em usar fragment? Talvez seja mais vantajoso nessa situação.

Comment: @AckLay na verdade eu já uso. Tem uma activity que mostra os frags com a lista com os 3 tipos de imagem que quero combinar

Comment: sim é possível, tenho um projeto em ki fiz isso, mas nn com imagens